# Implementation of Jquery Data Tale with Tree View from server side

Tags: jquery, treeview, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatable and want to implement tree view with it. I am using [Tree View](https://github.com/RoyLING/jquery.dataTables.TreeTable) plugin with it. There is no example for how implement tree view with serverside json response in datatable. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was the owner of the plugin, just found this question redirected from github. Did you already figure it out? In fact, no special requirement to the server response, just use whatever as you like. However, in order to make this work, you need to **implement `fnPreInit` callback to tell the parent/children relationship to the plugin**, which is actually required by the jquery tree table plugin. You could refer to the example snippet in the [README](https://github.com/RoyLING/jquery.dataTables.TreeTable/blob/master/README.md).

**Note:** this plugin was created to integrate DataTables with jquery tree table plugin v2.x. But the latest [tree plugin (v3.x)](http://plugins.jquery.com/treetable/) was totally rewritten by the author, backward incompatible :( So this integration plugin is deprecated now.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have used different approach to fulfill my requirement. But it would be better if you make it compatible again with datatable.